# Extracting text from string between two identical characters using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say I have the following string within a cell:

E. Stark, T. Lannister, A. Martell, P Baelish, B. Dondarrion, and J. Mormont. Increased levels of nudity across Westeros contributes to its sporadic seasonal climate. Nat. Proc. Aca. Sci. (2011) 3: 142-149.

And I want to extract only the title from this. The approach I am considering is to write a script that says "Pull text from this string, but only if it is more than 50 characters long." This way it only returns the title, and not stuff like " Stark, T" and " Martell, P". The code I have so far is:

```
Sub TitleTest()
    Dim txt As String
    Dim Output As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    j = 5
    Set rng = Range("A" & j) 'text is in cell A5
    txt = rng.Value 'txt is string
    i = 1

    While j <= 10 'there are five references between A5 and A10
    k = InStr(i, txt, ".") - InStr(i, txt, ". ") + 1 'k is supposed to be the length of the string returned, but I can't differenciate one "." from the other.

    Output = Mid(txt, InStr(i, txt, "."), k)
            If Len(Output) < 100 Then
                i = i + 1
            ElseIf Len(Output) > 10 Then
                Output = Mid(txt, InStr(i, txt, "."), InStr(i, txt, ". "))
                Range("B5") = Output
                j = j + 1
            End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

Of course, this would work well if it wasn't two "." I was trying to full information from. Is there a way to write the `InStr` function in such a way that it won't find the same character twice? Am I going about this in the wrong way?

Thanks in advance,

EDIT: Another approach that might work (if possible), is if I could have one character be " `any lower case letter`." and ".". Would even this be possible? I can't find any example of how this could be achieved...

Comment: Could you explain what the input string is like and what you want out?

Comment: formula wise, you can use SUBSTITUTE and FIND/SEARCH to assist

Comment: Input string is a bibliographic reference (hypothetical example used here) and the desired output is the title "Increased levels of nudity across Westeros contributes to its sporadic seasonal climate." in this case

Comment: You need to explain what the strings look like in more detail. The problem with splitting on "." is that there are (in general) a variable number of periods before the title and a variable number of periods after the title. A robust solution would probably require a list of permissible journal abbreviations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go, it works exactly as you wish. Judging from your code I am sure that you can adapt it for your needs quite quickly:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractTextSub()

    Debug.Print ExtractText("E. Stark, T. Lannister, A. Martell, P Baelish, B. Dondarrion, and J. Mormont. Increased levels of nudity across Westeros contributes to its sporadic seasonal climate. Nat. Proc. Aca. Sci. (2011) 3: 142-149.")

End Sub

Public Function ExtractText(str_text As String) As String

    Dim arr         As Variant
    Dim l_counter   As Long
    arr = Split(str_text, ".")

    For l_counter = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

        If Len(arr(l_counter)) > 50 Then
            ExtractText = arr(l_counter)
        End If

    Next l_counter

End Function
```

Edit: 5 votes in no time made me improve my code a bit :) This would return the longest string, without thinking of the 50 chars. Furthermore, on Error handlaer and a constant for the point. Plus adding a point to the end of the extract.

```
Option Explicit

Public Const STR_POINT = "."

Sub ExtractTextSub()

    Debug.Print ExtractText("E. Stark, T. Lannister, A. Martell, P Baelish, B. Dondarrion, and J. Mormont. Increased levels of nudity across Westeros contributes to its sporadic seasonal climate. Nat. Proc. Aca. Sci. (2011) 3: 142-149.")

End Sub

Public Function ExtractText(str_text As String) As String

    On Error GoTo ExtractText_Error

    Dim arr             As Variant
    Dim l_counter       As Long
    Dim str_longest     As String

    arr = Split(str_text, STR_POINT)

    For l_counter = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

        If Len(arr(l_counter)) > Len(ExtractText) Then
            ExtractText = arr(l_counter)
        End If

    Next l_counter

ExtractText = ExtractText & STR_POINT

On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function

ExtractText_Error:

MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & Err.Description 

End Function
```

Comment: Beat me to it! To OP: it should be noted that Split should be used with some caution.  It is important that you are certain that the data being "split" is properly delimited by the chosen character and that that delimiter is not used elsewhere in the text.  If the title, for example, featured a "." for a shortening, it would be split along that period.  Clever workarounds include splitting with a period and a comma, or setting up your data to use an irregular set of characters as delimeters initially (to be certain it won't show up organically in the data)

Comment: That is a reasonable heuristic, though short article names are not unheard of. It is definitely possible to have the title of an article be shorter than the name of one of the contributors. A more serious problem is that titles themselves often contain embedded periods. Still a good idea, so +1

Comment: Thanks everyone. Yes, this does work perfectly. Short titles and those with "." in the middle of it will fall through, so these will need to be checked manually. This is definitely a great starting point. Thanks a million!

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on the logic behind the line `If Len(arr(l_counter)) > Len(ExtractText) Then`? How can the length of the `Split` output ever be longer than the ExtractText?

Comment: @user1996971 write >Debug.Print ExtractText< before the if and you will see yourself. ExtractText is the string function itself, but it is used as a variable as well.